# Perl - Problem with splitting columns in tab delimited text file and replacing columns with new values

Tags: file, perl, split

I have a tab delim. text file comprised of a number of rows and columns.  I want to change the contents of the first two columns, then write the amended file to a new file.
Before changing , the first two columns of each line look something like this:

```
COLUMN1:                                              
dip:DIP-41935N|refseq:NP_056092|uniprotkb:Q96PU5    

COLUMN2:    dip:DIP-48957N|uniprotkb:P49281
```

I want them to just contain the id number at the end of each column, so I want them to be as follows:

```
COLUMN1:        Q96PU5          

COLUMN 2:       P49281
```

I have split the lines at the tab to get the individual columns.  Then split the first 2 columns to get the required ID number ($prot_id).  Then I have tried substituting the ID for the contents of columns 1 and 2.  However the output in the changed file is not as I expect.  It instead looks something like this:

```
  COLUMN1:                                           
Q96PU5|refseq:NP_056092|uniprotkb:Q96PU5    

COLUMN 2:
P49281|uniprotkb:P49281
```

Just the first part of the columns has been substituted.  I have been playing around with this for hours and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help greatly appreciated. 
My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use warnings;
use strict;


my $file = 'DIP.txt';

open(INFILE, $file) or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
open(my $outfile, '>', 'DIP_changed.txt'); 
my @lines = <INFILE>;


foreach $_ (@lines) {
    my @columns = split('\t', $_);

            my $col1 = $columns[0];
            my $col2 = $columns[1];


            my @split_col1 = split ('uniprotkb:', $col1);
            my @split_col2 = split ('uniprotkb:', $col2);

            my $prot_id1 = $split_col1[length(@split_col1)];
            my $prot_id2 = $split_col2[length(@split_col2)];

            print $prot_id1, "\n";

             s/$col1/$prot_id1/;
             s/$col2/$prot_id2/;

            print {$outfile} $_; 
}



exit;
```

Comment: `my $prot_id1 = $split_col1[length(@split_col1)];` isn't doing what you most likely intend - probably the last index of the array. `length` returns the number of characters in a string. To index the last element in the array, just use 'my $prot_id1 = $split_col1[ -1 ];`

Answer (score 2):

There's already some decent answers, but I'd like to show you a simpler solution. This script, you'd use like this:

```
$ script.pl DIP.txt > DIP_changed.txt
```

And the script itself is really just:

```
while (<>) {
    s/\S+uniprotkb:(\S+)/$1/;
    s/\S+uniprotkb:(\S+)/$1/;
    print;
}
```

It doesn't need to be more complicated than that.

Comment: That looks very simple!  Wouldn't that change every column in the file containing 'uniprot:' within it, ratehr than just the first 2 columns?

Comment: @James No, a regex match only executes once, unless you add the `/g` (global) option. So these two will change the first two matches, and no more.

Comment: @TLP But if the first two matches might not be in the first two columns, in which case you won't get the behavior specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

This is a neat Perl idiom - match a string on a regular expression like this

```
$columns[0]=~/:((\w|\d)*)$/;
```

(note that there are two atoms defined there with the parentheses) and assign the results of the matches (whatever is in the 1st, 2nd, and so on atoms) to an array - or to a set of scalar variables in an array list, like this:

```
($columns[0]) = $columns[0]=~/:((\w|\d)*)$/;
```

See, you were on the right track but you were making it harder than it needed to be :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'DIP.txt';

open(INFILE, $file) or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
open(my $outfile, '>', 'DIP_changed.txt');


foreach my $line (<INFILE>) {
    print "The input line is $line\n";
    my @columns = split('\t', $line);

    ($columns[0]) = $columns[0]=~/:((\w|\d)*)$/;
    ($columns[1]) = $columns[1]=~/:((\w|\d)*)$/;

    printf  "The output line is  %s\n", join ',', @columns;
    printf  $outfile join ',', @columns;

    }
```

Comment: I should have added - if there is any whitespace between the part you're looking for in each column (e.g. Q96PU5) and the tab then this regex won't match.  When I copied and pasted your sample data into a file I accidentally put a space in it and it did't find the match.  I think changing the regex to this: /:((\w|\d)*)\s*$/ would fix that.  (The \s* matches zero or more whitespace characters, but since that's after the atom and before the end-of-string '$' marker the whitespace won't be included in the match.)

Comment: Thanks for this, it does seem to work.  I don't quite understand what this part is doing though:

Comment: The strings we're trying to match have mixed digits and letters (e.g. Q96PU5) \w means "any word character" and will match letters.  \d means any digit and | means or so (\w|\d) will match any one character which is a letter or digit.  The * quantifier means "match the preceding thing zero or more times" so (\w|\d)* will match any sequence of letters and digits, like Q96PU5.  It might be better to use a + quantifier instead of * because + will match *one* or more.

Comment: Then put the colon : in front of that and the end-of-string marker after it and you get this :((\w|\d)*)$ which will match anything that looks like :Q96PU5 at the end of a string.  Wrapping it in parentheses means that the contents of that actual match, that is whatever matched the (\w|\d)* will be returned from the match.

Comment: DavidO's answer below was similar.  He used the regex ([^:]+)$ which just means match any character that's not a colon [^:] repeated one or more times + followed by the end of string.  I almost like this better than the regex I wrote; it's a little more say-what-you-mean-ish.  The only problem I see with that is that it will match and include in the result any whitespace which might exist before the end-of-string.  The first regex I posted will just break in the presence of such whitespace.  That's why I added the comment suggesting this /:((\w|\d)*)\s*$/ instead.

Comment: Ok, great, thank you for taking the time to explain all that :-)  If my id was not actually at the end of the string, but was instead at the beginning and the other stuff followed it, like this:  uniprotkb:Q96PU5|dip:DIP-41935N|refseq:NP_056092 how would I do it then? ^ signifies the beginning of a string, right?  something like this?   ~/^(*:((\w|\d))/\|);     (I've probably got the brackets all wrong there)

Answer (score 1):

ratsbane's answer was pretty good, but you probably want to know after hours of working *why* you got the answer you did.  The reason is that $col1 had a pipe in it.  That is an "OR" in a regex.  So when you tried to substitute for the regex $col1, you were doing a find and replace over

```
dip:DIP-41935N|refseq:NP_056092|uniprotkb:Q96PU5
```

Now as a regex, what does it match?  It matches only

```
dip:DIP-41935N
```

so **that** is what got replaced!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah, cool.  I never stopped to look at *why* his code wasn't working.  It's so easy to forget to escape patterns.

Comment: That's good to know, I just couldn't work it out!  So there's no way to get around that 'pipe' issue in the column using code based on what I already have?

Comment: Yes, you _can_ get around this issue by writing this: `s/\Q$col1\E/$prot_id1/;` (and the same for column 2 of course). But it is better to go with @TLP's solution.

Comment: Ok, but out of curiosity,t what  do the \Q and \E signify?

Comment: Within \Q and \E, metacharacters such as | and * and + and ? and friends lose their special meaning and are treated as plain characters.  So while /a|b/ matches a or b, /\Qa|b\E/ matches the three-character string "a|b".

Answer (score 1):

There's probably no really good reason to slurp the file in at the beginning, rather than processing it line by line.  Processing line by line will scale better.  With that in mind, I would do it this way:

```
use warnings;
use strict;


my $file = 'DIP.txt';

open my $in_fh, '<', $file or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>', 'new' . $file or die $!;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    next unless length $_; # Skip blank lines.
    my ( @columns ) = split /\s+/, $_; # Split on whitespace (you may prefer \t).
    foreach my $column ( @columns ) {
        ( $column ) = $column =~ m{([^:]+)$};
    }
    local $" = "\t";
    print $out_fh "@columns\n";
}
```

First, this uses the three arg version of open on both the input file and the output file.  This is a good habit to get into.  Next, it uses lexical filehandles instead of the old fileglob filehandles.  Lexicals auto-close when they pass out of scope, and don't become part of the global symbol table.

Next, the script reads the file and process it line by line, to avoid slurping.  This could be advantageous if the file potentially grows large, or if you're in an environment where memory usage is at a premium.  Unless you have a good reason to slurp, may as well get in the habit of not doing so.

Then I split on whitespace.  You could split on tabs.  Unless there's embedded whitespace in the columns either way works.  Then I iterate over the two columns, matching and capturing from each everything at the end of the column that is not a colon.  Or another way of putting it, everything that comes after the last colon.  I capture the result right back into the $column variable, which aliases the corresponding element in @columns.  That way, when I'm done @columns only holds my captures.

Finally, after processing the two columns, we localize $", assigning to it a tab character.  That way when we print the two columns by wrapping @columns in quotes, the interpolation automatically sticks a tab character between the columns again.  If you prefer a different character, you now know where to change it.

Then the while loop moves on to the next line.  Any blank lines will be skipped.

see perldoc open, perlretut, perlvar, and perlop for an explanation of three-arg open as well as lexical filehandles, an explanation of regexps, Perl's special variables such as $", and how quotish interpolation works.

Good question!